# Content Type Problem in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This codes forces Google Chrome to download the file as `.aspx` and for IE7 as `.htm`

```
    Dim sFileString As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("FileString")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileString) Then
        Dim bBuffer() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sFileString)
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ContentType = "application/text"
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment")
        Response.AddHeader("Filename", "ACHFile.txt")
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.Length)
    End If
```

I want it to download the file as `.txt` but didn't make it.

Comment: The answer has been deleted? The answer is `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ACHFile.txt")` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use `text/plain`

See:

MIME Type Detection in Internet Explorer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx

How To Raise a "File Download" Dialog Box for a Known MIME Type
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Update:

Also try

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download;");
```